# Resistor to ring and vice versa

Tags: gratis, android, ad-free

I am looking for an Android app that has 2 main features:

1. Input a resistor value (manually by typing via keyboard), output resistor rings
2. Input resistor rings (maually by choosing colors from a list or similar), output resistor values

Support for 4-ring resistors is enough, however 5-ring resistor support would be nice.

Such apps already exist, but I was unable to find one that fulfills my secondary needs:

- is gratis
- is ad-free
- has no in-app purchases
- absence of tons of other features

I am the youth leader of a electronics tinker club and I have to ensure that any app I recommend to the children and youngsters is safe to use.

I do not need:

- image recognition; taking a photo of a resistor
- support for SMD resistors

Comment: "Input"? How? Are you looking to use the camera and image recognition?

Comment: @Mawg: thanks for the clarification request. I updated the question

Comment: I wasn't sure; maybe you just wanted screen input. But, you know how it is - the more detail you give, then better the answer that you will get (I hope). If not, code the app yourself, or get one of the club to do it & give it away.

Comment: @Mawg: indeed, it's not that difficult. If there's no such app, I'll write it.

Comment: Or, you could tutor one of the club to do so, if interested

Answer (score 1):

For identifying resistors, I really like the input methods used at https://www.resistor-calculator.com/ and its belonging mobile apps. With few clicks (taps on mobile) all color and resistor values can be set and found quickly.

[image: screenshot of resistor rings from resistor-calculator.com]

The Android app **Resistor Code Calculator** is freely available from Play store:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vivid_planet.resistor

It works without network connection and simply displays resistor colors and values for 4 and 5 band, nothing else.

**Downside:** According to Google Play the app contains Ads. There is also no keyboard input of the resistor value, but maybe you can find some ideas for creating your own app :)

Comment: I was explicitly looking for an app without ads

Comment: Of course, and as no matching app exists you thought about building your own. My post was mainly meant to show how simple and efficient the input handling can be done. No unhandy color lists and dropdowns, like other calculators use. (Would have commented, but have not enough points for doing so.)